# Illustrator: how to align different elements of a layer without them collapsing together

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, path, shapes, alignment

I'm quite new to illustrator, but I'm having hard time trying to align the whole layer to the center of the artboard without its element collapsing all together, would you have any suggestions  how to do it? Thank you very much [image: sun all together]

[image: elements of the sun collapsed in the middle of the artboard]

Answer (score 4):

Group all the pieces in your first image.

Select them all and hit <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (or `Object > Group` from the menu).

Illustrator will then treat the group as a single object, and problem solved.

Comment: Although that has the downside that if the elements are in different layers (which here they aren't) they are now organized under the group in current layer. Which may affect drawing order and this can be a problem. But alas there is no good alternative to this workflow.

Comment: Yes, however, not much reason to use layering for this particular situation.